# html tag width on resize

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using h2 tag for heading in bootstrap.
i have something below structure

```
<div id="id2">
  <header>
    <div class="hideshow1"> Toggle this div </div>
    <div class="hideshow2"> Toggle this div </div>
    <h2> My Header very long </h2>
  </header>
  <div class="body1">
     This is my body 
   </div>
 </div>
```

what happens is when i resize window then my h2 tag does not display properly it just come down and display in another section in short it is messy.

What i would like to do is when there is no enough space for h2 then it should just display how many char fit in the space. something like **my header...**

below is my css for h2

```
#id2 > header h2 {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    height: 100%;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    line-height: 34px;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
}
```

It does not seem to work.. if any CSS expert could share some info.

Thank you

Regrads,
Mona

Comment: If possible, can create jsfiddle to demonstrate issue ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things you'll have to do to get this working. Your header will have to be set to `display: block` rather than `display: inline-block`, then you'll need to set `overflow: hidden` on the header as well as `text-overflow: ellipsis`.

Here's a sample [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pNMh8/1/)

EDIT: added a better jsfiddle link

Answer (score 1):

```
text-overflow:ellipsis;
```

will do that for you if the text does not fit in the element. However, h2 will stretch to fit the text by default, so you should also set a max-width so your h2 doesn't become too wide.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to remove

```
"display: inline-block;"
```